# Use toMatchObject with stringMatching(regexp) in Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm using JEST matcher `toMatchObject` to ensure that object contains several properties and some values are static while some other values should match to specific regexp

The problem is: when static value doesn't match, output shows mismatches in regexp values as well, despite they are fine

Code:

```
test("asdf", async () => {
  const actual = {
    a: "a_value",
    b: "b_value", 
    c: "c_value"
  }
  expect(actual).toMatchObject({
    a: expect.stringMatching("[a-z]_value"), 
    b: "b_value", 
  })

  expect(actual).toMatchObject({
    a: expect.stringMatching("[a-z]_value"), 
    b: "B_VALUE", 
  })
})
```

Output:

```
Expected value to match object:
  {"a": StringMatching /[a-z]_value/, "b": "B_VALUE"}
Received:
  {"a": "a_value", "b": "b_value", "c": "c_value"}
Difference:
- Expected
+ Received

  Object {
-   "a": StringMatching /[a-z]_value/,
-   "b": "B_VALUE",
+   "a": "a_value",
+   "b": "b_value",
  }
```

I want to see in output here only mismatched values, since regexp is fine:

```
   Object {
    -   "b": "B_VALUE",
    +   "b": "b_value",
```

[image: example]

Comment: Здравствуй Вадим! What you are seeing is a bug in how Jest is reporting the failing test. Your second test is failing: your property `a` is correct, but your property `b` is not correct. However, Jest is confused and is reporting them both as failing, when in reality it is only the `b` property that is incorrect

Comment: @MitchLillie, thank you for confirming. I've opened an issue in their tracker, https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6928

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in jest,  https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6928.

Comment: The mentioned issue/bug has been fixed/closed in the meantime, the fix is included in `jest@25.1.0`, released 2020-01